# How does the SECTIONS directive in OpenMP distribute work?

Tags: openmp

In OpenMP when using `omp sections`, will the threads be distributed to the blocks inside the *sections*, or will each thread be assigned to each sections?

When `nthreads == 3`:

```
#pragma omp sections
{
    #pragma omp section
    { 
        printf ("id = %d, \n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }

    #pragma omp section
    { 
        printf ("id = %d, \n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
id=1
id=1
```

But when I execute the following code:

```
#pragma omp sections
{
    #pragma omp section
    { 
        printf ("id = %d, \n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }

    #pragma omp section
    { 
        printf ("id = %d, \n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
}

#pragma omp sections
{
    #pragma omp section
    { 
        printf ("id = %d, \n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }

    #pragma omp section
    { 
        printf ("id = %d, \n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
id=1
id=1

id=2
id=2
```

From these output I can't understand what the concept of sections is in OpenMP.

Comment: This article would be interesting to read: http://jakascorner.com/blog/2016/05/omp-sections.html

Answer (score 111):

The code posted by the OP will never execute in parallel, **because the `parallel` keyword does not appear**. The fact that the OP got ids different from 0 shows that probably his code was embedded in a parallel directive. However, this is not clear from his post, and might confuse beginners.

The minimum sensible example is (for the first example posted by the OP):

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
    #pragma omp section
    { 
        printf ("id = %d, \n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }

    #pragma omp section
    { 
        printf ("id = %d, \n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
}
```

On my machine, this prints

```
id = 0,
id = 1,
```

showing that the two sections are being executed by different threads.

It's worth noting that however this code can not extract more parallelism than two threads: if it is executed with more threads, the other threads don't have any work to do and will just sit down idle.

Comment: This answer does not explain why the OP shows `id=1` and `id=2`. It's very likely the program the OP posted was running in parallel.

Answer (score 30):

The idea of parallel sections is to give the compiler a hint that the various (inner) sections can be performed in parallel, for example:

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
   #pragma omp section
   {
      /* Executes in thread 1 */
   } 
   #pragma omp section
   {
      /* Executes in thread 2 */
   } 
   #pragma omp section
   {
      /* Executes in thread 3 */
   } 
   /* ... */
}
```

This is a hint to the compiler and not guaranteed to happen, though it should. Your output is kind of what is expected; it says that there are #sections being executed in thread id 1, and in thread 2. The output order is non-deterministic as you don't know what thread will run first.

Comment: -1 Your answer contains a lot of inaccuracies. You can't be sure that different sections are assigned to different threads. The output order is non-deterministic only inside a single `sections` construct, not among two different `sections` (implicit barrier at the end of the construct)

Answer (score 13):

Change the first line from

> #pragma omp sections

into

> #pragma omp parallel sections

"parallel" directive ensures that the two sections are assigned to two threads.
Then, you will receive the following output 
id = 0,
id = 1,

Answer (score 11):

You are missing `parallel` keyword.
The `parallel` keyword triggers the openmp run in parallel.

Answer (score 7):

According to [OpenMP standard 3.1](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.1.pdf), section 2.5.2 (emphasis mine):

> The sections construct is a noniterative worksharing construct that
>   contains a set of structured blocks that **are to be distributed among
>   and executed by the threads in a team**. Each structured block is
>   **executed once by one of the threads** in the team in the context of its
>   implicit task.
>
> ...
>
> Each structured block in the sections construct is preceded by a
>   section directive except possibly the first block, for which a
>   preceding section directive is optional. **The method of scheduling the
>   structured blocks among the threads in the team is implementation
>   defined**. There is an **implicit barrier** at the end of a sections
>   construct unless a nowait clause is specified.

So, applying these rules to your case, we can argue that:

1. the different structured blocks identified in a `sections` directive are **executed once, by one thread**. In other words you have always four prints, whichever the number of threads
2. the blocks in the first `sections` will be executed (in a non-deterministic order) **before** the blocks in the second `sections` (also executed in a non-deterministic order). This is because of the **implicit barrier** at the end of the work-sharing constructs
3. the scheduling is **implementation defined**, so that you can't possibly control which thread has been assigned a given section

Your output is thus due to the way your scheduler decided to assign the different blocks to the threads in the team.

Comment: Sir, In the comment of the accepted answer, you commented `You can't be sure that different sections are assigned to different threads`. But, the 1st para in section 2.5.2 that you've referred speaks the similar thing. What's the difference?

Comment: @jos The difference is that the standard does not prescribe **how** blocks are distributed. `The method of scheduling the structured blocks among the threads in the team is implementation defined`. The OP shows that in a particular run the 2 blocks of the first `sections` are assigned both to thread 1, likewise for thread 2 on the blocks for the second section.

Answer (score 3):

It may be helpful to add more information to the output line and to add more sections (if you have the thread-count)

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
    #pragma omp section
    {
        printf ("section 1 id = %d, \n", omp_get_thread_num()); 
    }
    #pragma omp section
    {
        printf ("section 2 id = %d, \n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
    #pragma omp section
    {
        printf ("section 3 id = %d, \n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
}
```

Then you may get more interesting output like this:

```
section 1 id = 4,
section 3 id = 3,
section 2 id = 1,
```

which shows how the sections may be executed in any order, by any available thread.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 'nowait' tells the compiler that threads do not need to wait to ***exit*** the section. In Fortran 'nowait' goes at the end of the loop or section, which makes this more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The `#pragma omp parallel` is what creates (forks) the threads initially. Only on creating the threads, will the other Openmp constructs be of significance.

Hence,
Method 1:

```
// this creates the threads
#pragma omp parallel
{
   #pragma omp sections
   {
     #pragma omp section
     {
        // code here
     }
     #pragma omp section
     {
        // code here
     }
   }
}
```

or

Method 2:

```
// this creates the threads and creates sections in one line
#pragma omp parallel sections
   #pragma omp section
   {
      // code here
   }
   #pragma omp section
   {
      // code here
   }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

If you want really start different threads in different sections, the `nowait` clause tells compiler that threads do not need to wait to enter a section.

```
#pragma omp parallel sections nowait
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: This is just plain wrong. `nowait` means removing the implied barrier at the end of a worksharing construct. There is no barrier on entry.

Comment: I agree with Massimiliano; Moreover, if u try to compile nowait with parallel it says that 'nowait' is not valid for 'omp parallel sections nowait'