# Difference between single and sections directive in OpenMP

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, directive

For my understanding,
I can use `single` directive do the same work as using `sections` just add `nowait` flags

The following code has no different to me compare to `section` directive:

```
    void main(){
    #pragma omp parallel
        {
            int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    #pragma omp single nowait
            {
                printf("Thread %d in #1 single construct.\n", tid);
            }
    #pragma omp single nowait
            {
                printf("Thread %d in #2 single construct.\n", tid);
            }
    #pragma omp single nowait
            {
                printf("Thread %d in #3 single construct.\n", tid);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can any one give me some examples using `sections` and `single` directives in different scenarios?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost, `single` and `sections` directives have clearly different semantic purposes when it comes to reading code and using one to mimic the other may be highly misleading.

Regarding the technicalities, `single` is the only worksharing directive to support the `copyprivate` clause, which:

> ... provides a mechanism to use a private variable
>   to broadcast a value from the data environment of one implicit task to
>   the data environments of the other implicit tasks belonging to the
>   parallel region.

The `sections` worksharing construct on the other hand supports `lastprivate` and `reduction` clauses, which `single` does not.

Finally, note that your snippet:

```
#pragma omp single nowait
        {
            printf("Thread %d in #1 single construct.\n", tid);
        }
#pragma omp single nowait
        {
            printf("Thread %d in #2 single construct.\n", tid);
        }
#pragma omp single nowait
        {
            printf("Thread %d in #3 single construct.\n", tid);
        } // No barrier here
```

does not mimic a `sections`, but a `sections nowait`. To mimic a `sections` you must remember to have the very last `single` construct maintaining its implicit barrier.

Comment: If i want to make a task manager function, which directive should i choose?

Comment: @CharlesChow I don't understand what you mean by "a task manager function". If you want to use task level parallelism, OpenMP 3.X and 4.0 support `task` directives.

Comment: I mean a program that registers new tasks and assign each task to threads. You mentioned that I should leave a barrier for single directive, does it means that I just remove `nowait` in the last section of `single`?

Comment: I think it may be of help for you to read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13789119/771663) on the differences between sections and tasks.

Answer (score 2):

in some cases, `single nowait` construct might appear to behave the same way as the `sections` construct.  However, the OpenMP specification only requires that only one thread executes the `single` construct.  It does not require that idle threads take on the other subsequent constructs.  You can't simply rely on this behavior for all OpenMP implementations.  Most will do what you expect, but there are no guarantees.

The other thing worth mentioning is that most implementations use a ticketing system assign  the `single` regions to threads.  The usual code transformation for `sections` is to map to to the `for` working sharing construct by translating the sections construct into a `for` loop and using a `switch` statement for the `section` constructs.  So, there are some more guarantees about the execution.

Cheers,
        -michael

Comment: Am i right saying that even in `sections` the specifications does not `require that idle threads take on the other subsequent constructs`? (See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19306248/771663) for a broader explanation of what I mean, i.e. schedule is implementation defined)

Comment: Your are right.  If there are less sections that there are threads some might remain idle.  With the single pattern above, technically only one thread might execute, although there are several regions that could run in parallel.