# How to run two set of code in parallel using openmp in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I have two function which are not related to each other for example:

```
int add(int num)
{ 
     int sum=0;
     for(i=0;i<num;++i)
         sum+=i;
    return sum;
}

int mul(int num)
{  
    int mul=1;
    for(int i=1;i<num;++i)
       mul * i;
    return mul;
}
```

and I am suing them as follow:

```
auto x=add(100);
auto m=mul(200);
cout<<a<< "    " <<m<<endl;
```

How can I run them in parallel using OpenMP? I know that I can run them in parallel if I create a new thread and run one of the functions in that thread and implement a sync mechanizim to make sure that both threads finisshes by time that cout is called.

Also I know that I can use openMP parallel for for my loops, but assume that it is not there.

Comment: @VladimirF Do you mean similar to the code presented at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770911/how-does-the-sections-directive-in-openmp-distribute-work

Comment: yes, something like that

Comment: @VladimirF Pleae put your comment in an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to sort out this problem in OpenMP is the `sections` construct. It enables you to define parts of your sequential code, that can be computed concurrently by different threads. Each section starts with the `omp section` directive/pragma.