# How can i tell one thread / one function with openMP?

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm beginning in openMP and I try to use openMP in my code source. I have four functions and I would like to give for each thread one function. Here is my code:

```
  int a,b,c,d;
  omp_set_num_threads(4);
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
     a=SetHist1(int (Convert_Mask0(mask)),1);

     b=SetHist2(int (Convert_Mask45(mask)),1);

     c=SetHist3(int (Convert_Mask90(mask)),1);

     d=SetHist4(int (Convert_Mask135(mask)),1);
    }
```

but this does  not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SECTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770911/how-does-the-sections-directive-in-openmp-distribute-work) directives to make each `SetHistX` on different threads. You could also use [TASK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24457_01/html/E21996/glmpw.html) directives depending of your needs.

Differences of use between sections and tasks are available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788638/difference-between-section-and-task-openmp).

Using sections directives, your code would look like something like this :

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
   #pragma omp section
   {
   a=SetHist1(int (Convert_Mask0(mask)),1);
   }
   #pragma omp section
   {
   b=SetHist2(int (Convert_Mask45(mask)),1);
   }
   #pragma omp section
   {
   c=SetHist3(int (Convert_Mask90(mask)),1);
   }
   #pragma omp section
   {
   d=SetHist4(int (Convert_Mask135(mask)),1);
   }
}
```